# Скрипт выбирает один элемент и не регирует на innerHtml

Tags: javascript, queryselector, queryselectorall

Есть такой скрипт

```js
function chooseElement(e) {

  var selectr = document.querySelectorAll(e);
  for (var i = 0; i < selectr.length; i++) {

    return selectr[i];

  }

}
 var x = chooseElement('.hello');
  x.style.color = "red";
 var y = chooseElement('.hello2');
  y.innerHtml = "Span";
```

```html
<span class="hello">Мой тег span</span><br>
<span class="hello">Мой тег span</span><br>
<span class="hello">Мой тег span</span><br>
<span class="hello">Мой тег span</span><br>
<span class="hello2">Мой тег span2</span><br>
<span class="hello2">Мой тег span2</span><br>
<span class="hello2">Мой тег span2</span><br>
```

Вопрос, почему он выбирает только один элемент а innerHtml отказывается работать?

Comment: а как ты думаешь что делает этот код *for (var i = 0; i < selectr.length; i++) {

    return selectr[i];

  }* ?  ....... и второй вопрос: где тут `innerHtml` ?

Comment: ` for (var i = 0; i < selectr.length; i++) { return selectr[i]; } ` выбирает все элементы

Comment: выбирает все элементы строка `var selectr = document.querySelectorAll(e);`, а не цикл..... это написано в **[документации по querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая же итерация цикла натыкается на `return`, поэтому выходит из функции, возвращая только первый элемент.
Свойства `innerHtml` нет, есть `innerHTML`:

```js
function chooseElement(e) {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(e)); // Выбираем элементы и перегоняем их в массив
}

let x = chooseElement('.hello');
x.forEach(x => x.style.color = "red");

let y = chooseElement('.hello2');
y.forEach(y => y.innerHTML = "Span");
```

```html
<span class="hello">Мой тег span</span><br>
<span class="hello">Мой тег span</span><br>
<span class="hello">Мой тег span</span><br>
<span class="hello">Мой тег span</span><br>
<span class="hello2">Мой тег span2</span><br>
<span class="hello2">Мой тег span2</span><br>
<span class="hello2">Мой тег span2</span><br>
```

Comment: А как сделать чтобы о вернул все значения

Comment: @Duoxx, обновил пример.

Comment: а как чтобы выборка элементов происходила в функции?

Comment: чтобы писать не писать `y.forEach(y => y.innerHTML = "Span");` а `y.innerHTML = "Span"`

Comment: @Duoxx, возвращается массив элементов, тут либо проходи массивом, либо возвращай один элемент, к которому можно применить `y.innerHTML = 'Span';`.

Comment: а как выбрать элементы в функции